# Python Dump API Output into DataFrame Cell

Tags: python, pandas, api, dataframe

I have a dataframe where I go through each of the rows and look at the columns to carry out a scaleserp API lookup

DF

```
Name                   Company       Console        Search
Phill Spencer          Microsoft      Xbox One      Phill Spencer Microsoft
Larry Hryb             Microsoft      Xbox One      Larry Hryb Microsoft
Bill Gates             Microsoft      Xbox 360      Bill Gates Microsoft 
Kenichiro Yoshida      Sony           PS4           Kenichiro Yoshida Sony
Howard Stringer        Sony           PS5           Howard Stringer PS5
```

So I will take the SEARCH column and use that as my search parameter.

The output that is given from the API i would then like to put in the column next to it so that the result for each each is in the cell that matches.

DF

```
Name                   Company       Console        Search                       API Result
Phill Spencer          Microsoft      Xbox One      Phill Spencer Microsoft
Larry Hryb             Microsoft      Xbox One      Larry Hryb Microsoft
Bill Gates             Microsoft      Xbox 360      Bill Gates Microsoft 
Kenichiro Yoshida      Sony           PS4           Kenichiro Yoshida Sony
Howard Stringer        Sony           PS5           Howard Stringer PS5
```

API Result Example:

```
{'title': '25 Jun 1914 - Advertising - Trove', 'link': 'https://trove.nla.gov.au/newspaper/article/7280119', 'snippet_matched': ['()', 'charge', 'Dan Whit'], 'snippet': 'I Iron roof, riltibcd II (),. Line 0.139.5. wai at r ar ... Propertb-« entired free of charge. Line 2.130.0 ... AT Dan Whit",\'»\', 6il 02 sturt »L, Prlnce\'»~Brti\'»e,. Line 3.12.0.'}
{'snippet': "Mary Bardwell is in charge of ... I() •. Al'companit'd by: Choppf'd Chitkf'n Li\\f>r Palt·. 1h!iiSC'o Gret'n Salad g iii ... of the overtime as Dan Whit-.", 'title': 'October 16,1980 - Bethlehem Public Library', 
'link': 'http://www.bethlehempubliclibrary.org/webapps/spotlight/years/1980/1980-10-16.pdf', 'snippet_matched': ['charge', '()', 'Dan Whit'], 'date': '16 Oct 1980'}
{'snippet': 'CONGRATULATIONS TO DAN WHIT-. TLE ON THE ... jailed and beaten dozens of times. In one of ... ern p()rts ceased. The MIF is not only\xa0...', 'title': 'extensions of remarks - US Government Publishing Office', 'link': 'https://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/pkg/GPO-CRECB-1996-pt5/pdf/GPO-CRECB-1996-pt5-7-3.pdf', 'snippet_matched': ['DAN WHIT', 'jailed', '()'], 'date': '26 Apr 1986'}
{'snippet': 'ILLUSTRATION BY DAN WHIT! By Matt Manning ... ()n the one hand, there are doctors on both ... self-serving will go to jail at the beginning of\xa0...', 'title': 'The BG News May 23, 2007 - ScholarWorks@BGSU - Bowling ...', 'link': 'https://scholarworks.bgsu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=8766&context=bg-news', 'snippet_matched': ['DAN WHIT', '()', 'jail'], 'date': '23 May 2007'}
{'snippet': '$19.95 Charge card number SERVICE HOURS: ... Explorer Advisor Dan Whit- ... lhrr %(OnrwflC or ()utuflrueonlinelfmarketing (arnpaigfl%? 0I - .', 
'title': '<%BANNER%> TABLE OF CONTENTS HIDE Section A: Main ...', 'link': 'https://ufdc.ufl.edu/UF00028295/00194', 'snippet_matched': ['Charge', 'Dan Whit', '()'], 'date': 'Listings 1 - 800'}
{'title': 'Lledo Promotional,Bull Nose Morris,Dandy,Desperate Dan ...', 'link': 'https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Lledo-Promotional-Bull-Nose-Morris-Dandy-Desperate-Dan-White-Van-/233817683840', 'snippet_matched': ['charges'], 'snippet': 'No additional import charges on delivery. This item will be sent through the Global Shipping Programme and includes international tracking. Learn more- opens\xa0...'}




for Searching in Search_List:

params = {
        'api_key': '',
        'q': (Searching),
        'gl': 'uk',
        'hl': 'en',
        'location': 'United Kingdom',
        'google_domain': 'google.co.uk',
        'device': 'desktop',
        'output': 'json',
        'num': '20',
        'include_html': 'false'
}

api_result = requests.get('https://api.scaleserp.com/search', params, verify=False)

result = api_result.json()

for ser in result['organic_results']:
    Extracted_data = {key: ser[key] for key in ser.keys()
    & {'title', 'link', 'snippet_matched', 'date', 'snippet'}}
```

Comment: I noticed that the example source DF has a weird structure. Sometimes you use `Console` value sometimes `Company` value in `Search` term generation. I hope this is the expected behaviour and we are just missing part of the logic but otherwise be wary that this might cause issues in the results of the API

Answer (score 0):

Not very clear if the response examples are coming in a list format or those are separate results for separate api calls so I had to generalize the approach.

You can use `json.dumps(dictionary)` to safely convert the dictionary into a string that can be later parsed if needed.

Generate dictionary holding your search and response pairs and convert it to DataFrame:

```
result_dict = {'Search': ['search_term_1', 'search_term_2', ....], 
               'API Result': [json.dumps(api_response_1), json.dumps(api_response_2), ....]}
result_df = pd.DataFrame(result_dict)
```

Once converted you can merge the `source_df` with `result_df` on `Search` column:

```
final_df = source_df.merge(result_df, how='left', on='Search')
```

Please note that if you already have `API Result` in `source_df` then after merging you will get 2 columns with changed names. To avoid that simply remove the empty `API Result` column from the `source_df` before merging.